# Eliminate reference to chapter in table caption (memoir class)

Tags: tables, floats, numbering, captions, memoir

I'm editing a book using the *memoir* class. Each chapter has a different author, and I restart numbering of all elements at the start of each chapter. So far, so good. However, I want to eliminate the chapter number that occurs in front of tables and figures (e.g. **Table 1**, not **Table 0.1**). I put this into my preamble, but it does only have an effect on footnotes and section titels.

```
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
```

I suspected the fact that I use the caption-package with the memoir class was what caused the problem. Removing this did however not help.

The code runs like this:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \captionof{table}{\emph{some caption}}
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
        \hline & \textbf{column A}  & \textbf{column B}  \\
        \hline  \textbf{Alpha}  & a  & b  \\
        \textbf{Beta}  & a  & b  \\
        \textbf{Gamma}  & a  & b \\
        \hline  \textbf{Total} & 100  & 100  \\

        \hline \label{fig1}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I've been reading he memoir manual and poking around the web all day, but I haven't got any closer to solving this problem.

Grateful for any help.

UPDATE:

This is my main document. I didn't want to include it, because it is loooooong.

```
\documentclass [paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, 11 pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais, english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{phonetic}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
\usepackage[tablename=Tab.]{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
 \setfloatadjustment{figure}{\small\centering}
\setfloatadjustment{table}{\small\centering}

\makeatletter

\preto{\@ex}{\topsep=0pt \parskip=0pt \parsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt }
\makeatother


\titleformat{\section}{\normalsize \bfseries}{\thesection}{1.75em}{\textsc}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize \bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\emph}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize \mdseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\emph}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\firstrefdash}{}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\makeatletter
\let\@afterindenttrue\@afterindentfalse
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}


\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{francais}

\frontmatter

\selectlanguage{francais}

\tableofcontents*


\include{introduction}

\newpage

\mainmatter

\part{La langue française}

\include{somepaper}

\backmatter

\include{index}

\end{document}
```

The problems I'm experiencing is in the `{somepaper}` under `\mainmatter`. (Actually, in all papers that contain tables or figures.) I tried `\stepcounter{table}`, which removed the numbering all together.

Comment: Are you using `\mainmatter` in your master document? Because that changes the numbering of things like this. As always a full minimal example helps a lot more than sniplets like this.

Comment: That is not a minimal example. This has nothing to do with the contents of your table. We need something we can copy'n'paste and use as is without having to add anything. Here we would have to guess your preamble.

Comment: You could replace \captionof with  \stepcounter{table}
 \begin{center}
 \textbf{Table \thetable:} \emph{some text}
 \end{center}

Comment: That is hardly *minimal*, move the counterwithout *after* `\mainmatter`

Answer (score 5):

`\mainmatter` does a few things

- resets `secnumdepth` to `mxsecnumdepth`
- reset the `page` counter to start from one and be normal numbers
- reset the `figure` and `table` counters into .

So you have two choices

1. move your `\counterwithout` stuff *after* `\mainmatter`, or
2. use this

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand\@memmain@floats{}
   \makeatother
   ```

This is the macro that resets the `figure` and `table` inside `\mainmatter`, so now it does nothing.