# Continuous Figures Numbering in Memoir

Tags: floats, numbering, memoir

I want to number my figures as Figure 1, 2, ... throughout the document.
I checked the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/continuous-numbering-of-figures-and-tables) and it works perfectly. However, when I use `\mainmatter` in memoir class it returns. (If you comment the `\mainmatter line in my code it will work, but I need the`\mainmatter`)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\begin{document}
    \mainmatter    %when using this the numbering changes
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Caption 2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Use the `\counterwithout` command after the `\mainmatter`.

Comment: Wow, three answers in less than 15 seconds. I'm quite impressed :)

Comment: lol, I didn't think of placing it after the \mainmatter. That was fast. thnx

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to load `chngcntr`, as  `memoir` implements `\counterwithout`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Eliminate reference to chapter in table caption (`memoir` class)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155775/5764)

Comment: Also see the end of section **6.1 LOGICAL DIVISIONS** in the [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf). There is a reference on code required for continuous float numbering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place the `\counterwithout` calls **after** `\mainmatter`.

Explanation:

`\mainmatter` is actually a command that allows `\mainmatter*` as well, the starred version calls `\@memmain@floats`, which in turn uses `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}` etc. Later, `\@memmain` calls `\@smemmain`, so the previous `\counterwithout` is reversed.

In the very end `\mainmatter` does the same as `\mainmatter*` but additionally switches to `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

```
\newcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \@ifstar{\@smemmain}{\@memmain}}
\newcommand\@memmain@floats{%
   \counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
   \counterwithin{table}{chapter}
}
\newcommand*{\@smemmain}{%
  \@mainmattertrue
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{maxsecnumdepth}}
  \ifartopt
    \if@twoside
      \cleardoublepage
    \else
      \clearpage
    \fi
  \else
    \cleardoublepage
    \@memmain@floats
  \fi}
\newcommand{\@memmain}{%
  \@smemmain\pagenumbering{arabic}}
```

Real code...

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter    %when using this the numbering changes

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Caption 2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should wait 10 minutes to accept this as an answer